# Physijs, combining movement and physics

Tags: javascript, three.js, physics, physijs

I've been looking around for a while now for a conclusion for this, but I seem to be unable to find any solution to this.

I'm trying to create a simple scene to get a little platform action to work using THREE.JS and PHYSI.JS. I have one flat box with a mass of 0 to act as my workd, and a box mesh to act as my character. The site of Physijs appears to suggest that I set the `__dirtyPosition` variable to `true`. The problem here is this: __dirtyPosition messes with the physics. As I move my character off the edge of the level, he's not falling. In fact, it seems to stop halfway the world cube when it does collide.

When I try to update the position without applying `__dirtyPosition`, the cube gets put back in it's place. It trembles a bit as if it's having a tiny seizure and that's it. It'd be great if I could use both physics and movement, using Physi for just collision feels kind of like overdoing it. Here's how I do it now, clearly the wrong way:

```
level1.generateScene = function()
{
   level1.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, this.cameraWidth / this.cameraHeight, 0.1, 1000);

   level1.material = new AdapterEngine.createBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00}); //Threejs basic material
   level1.ground = new AdapterEngine.createBoxMesh(5, 0.1, 5, level1.material, 0); //Physijs box mesh with a mass of 0

   level1.playerMaterial = new AdapterEngine.createBasicMaterial({color:0x0000ff}, 0.6, 0.3); //Physijs basic material with a fruction of 0.6, and a restitution of 0.3
   level1.player = new AdapterEngine.createBoxMesh(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, level1.playerMaterial, 0.1); //Physijs box mesh with a mass of 0.1
   level1.player.y = 50; //yes, it should fall down for a bit.

   level1.scene.add(level1.ground);
   level1.scene.add(level1.player);

   level1.camera.position.z = 5;
   level1.camera.position.y = 1.4;
   level1.activeCamera = level1.camera;
   level1.controls.init();
}
```

This is the function where the 'level', with both character and world gets created. What the level object also contains, is an update function that plays when after the requestAnimationframe function is called, and right before the renderer renders.

```
level1.update = function()
{
   this.scene.simulate();

   level1.player.__dirtyPosition = true;
   if(level1.controls.isKeyDown('RIGHT')) level1.xvelocity = 0.1;
   else if(level1.controls.isKeyDown('LEFT')) level1.xvelocity = -0.1;
   else if(level1.controls.isKeyUp('RIGHT') || level1.controls.isKeyUp('LEFT')) level1.xvelocity = 0;

   level1.player.rotation.x = 0;
   level1.player.rotation.y = 0;
   level1.player.rotation.z = 0;

   level1.player.position.x = level1.player.position.x + 0.5*level1.xvelocity;
}
```

I know similar questions have popped up, but none have really yielded satisfactory answers. I am genuinely at a loss of what to do, or which functions I should use.

*edit*
I forgot to add this part: I've been using a little framework that determines whether I should get a THREE.js object or a PHYSI.js object that works as a bridge between my game and my libraries. These follow the same parameters as THREE.js and PHYSI.js do, I have marked with comments which function returns which type of object.

Comment: I love how so many physics engines simply don't implement a proper kinematic character controller. Wait no, the other then. Hate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. First of all, you should **NOT** use `__dirtyPosition` to work with speed. I recommend using `setLinearVelocity` and `getLinearVelocity`:

```
level1.update = function(){
    this.scene.simulate();

    // Conditions...

    var oldVector = this.player.getLinearVelocity(); // Vector of velocity the player already has
    var playerVec3 = new THREE.Vector3(oldVector.x + .5 * this.xvelocity, oldVector.y, oldVector.z);
    this.player.setLinearVelocity(playerVec3); // We use an updated vector to redefine its velocity
}
```

Second of all, the reason you have this problem is probably because you didn't set the `__dirtyRotation` flag to `true`. You had a small area where you wanted to reset the rotation. Other than that, I don't see anything wrong from what you've posted.

Comment: Hey quick question. I'm trying to do a basic dogfighting thing and have had decent success except I'm at the point where I need to be able to move along in a straight line instead of fight inertia forces all the time.

I could just use setlinearvelocity but I'm certain this is going to mess up physics collisions. How does one go about dealing with a plane crashing into a wall at 45 degrees when the plane's movement isn't set by physics.
 Is there a way to achieve airplane-like steering using applyForce?

Answer (score 0):

For just a single cube character movement,
 try `object.setLinearVelocity(vector)` instead of using `object.__dirtyPosition`,

I think `__dirtyPosition` generally disables most of physics effects